# Using ProcessBuilder to compile multiple java files throws File not found error

Tags: java, compilation

I have simple java program for compiling java classes.
I created a JAR of this program and when I run it on Ubuntu I pass to the jar the path of folder with java files.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        compile(args[0]);
    }
    //pathToFiles - is a value from command line arguments
    private static void compile(String pathToFiles) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<>();
        cmdList.add("javac");
        cmdList.add(pathToFiles); 
        System.out.println("cmd: "+cmdList);


        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList);
        Process process = pb.start();
        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
        if (exitValue != 0) {
            generateCompileException(process);
        }


    }
    //method just generates error message if there was an error
    private static void generateCompileException(Process process){
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        try (final BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()))) {
            String line;
            if ((line = b.readLine()) != null)
                response.append(line);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(response.toString());
    }
}
```

When I pass path containing single java file it works:

```
java -jar co-1.jar /home/admin/test2/Calculator.java
```

But I want to compile multiple files. When I pass path containing multiple files I get error: file not found.

```
java -jar co-1.jar '/home/admin/test2/*.java'
```

[image]

PS: If I run a javac command manually with multiple files, it will work:
[image]

###################################

**UPDATE:**

I've added bash command to ProcessBuilder:

```
private static void compile(String pathToFiles) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<>();
    cmdList.add("bash");
    cmdList.add("-c");
    cmdList.add("javac");
    cmdList.add(pathToFiles);
    System.out.println("Processor builder command: "+cmdList);
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList);
    Process process = pb.start();
    int exitValue = process.waitFor();
    if (exitValue != 0) {
        System.out.println("Finished with error. Exit value: "+exitValue);
        generateCompileException(process);
    }
}
```

But process withished with error code 2 with empty response from ProcessBuilder.

PS: RuntimeException was thrown by this line: `throw new RuntimeException(response.toString());`
[image]

Comment: *"If I run a javac command manually with multiple files, it will work"* But you don't use quotes. Does it still work if you use quotes?

Comment: Quotes here are used for passing the path to command line arguments. In the code the quotes get removed. But anyway, I tried with quotes and without quotes. It didn't help to fix the problem

Comment: It was not my question. Did you try running `javac '/home/admin/test2/*.java'` on the command line?

Comment: Yes, sure. I tried it. this command doesn't work with quotes. But I don't see the correlation with the problem

Comment: Then it's normal that `java -jar co-1.jar '/home/admin/test2/*.java'` doesn't work, because it does the same thing as `javac '/home/admin/test2/*.java'`.

Comment: please read my comments above. It's absolutely not the same thing

Comment: @AlexanderTukanov The updated bash variant command isn't as I suggested, you need 3 parameter command `("bash", "-c", commandContainingWildcard)` and if bash or javac isn't on your path you must fully qualify the path too.

Comment: @DuncG It works! Thanks a lot! I spend a week for it... 
Now I run it as three args: `[bash, -c, javac /home/admin/test2/*.java]`
But why it didn't work with four args: `[bash, -c, javac, /home/admin/test2/*.java]` ??

Comment: Compare running `bash -c "ls /"` with `bash -c ls /`.  By the way, you may encounter new problems with your code now, I shall append suggested changes to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProcessBuilder will not evaluate wildcards, as that is a feature of your terminal (such as bash). If you want wildcard to be expanded you need to run bash inside `ProcessBuilder` command, such as:

```
String commandContainingWildcard = "javac /blah/*.java";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", commandContainingWildcard);
... // start() etc
```

For the above to work you need to have "bash" or whatever shell you use in your path, otherwise you will need to use full path to bash (such as "/bin/bash").

The third argument for command to compile must exactly match what works inside your terminal and must be the entire value not "javac" followed by wildcard. Remove single quotes around *.java (so that ProcessBuilder is provided with three command line parameters, not four or more).

However I suggest that ProcessBuilder with bash isn't the best way to do this work. You could try Java compiler tool interface, and get rid of wildcard by easy use of `Files.find(dir, 1, (p,a) -> p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".java"))` to scan for all java files and join the paths explicitly for compilation.

**UPDATE**

Having now resolved your problem you may now find that the javac process fails / freezes due the incorrect way you read the stderr stream - this needs to happen at same time as stdout and before `process.waitFor()`. An easy fix is to consume stdout+stderr together:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true); 
Process process = pb.start();
ByteArrayOutputStream response = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
process.getInputStream().transferTo(response);
int exitValue = process.waitFor();
if (exitValue != 0) {
    System.out.println("Finished with error. Exit value: "+exitValue);
    throw new RuntimeException(new String(response.toByteArray()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this commad, but the ProcessBuilder finished with error code 2 and I get no responce from it. Please, read the update in the post, I added new screenshot there.

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes and use the command as below.

```
java -cp co-1.jar:/home/admin/test2/* Main.class <args>
```

See also

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

PS: Unix uses :(colon) as delimiter and windows uses ;(semi-colon) delimiter to separate multiple paths.

Comment: It throws `invalid flag: /home/admin/test2/Calculator.class`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please add correct path to your co-1.jar

Comment: co-1.jar is not classpath, it's the compiler for the files located in test2 folder

Comment: co-1.jar needs to be in classpath. Whatever is the path to co-1.jar you need to add it to the class path like below

java -cp path/to/co-1.jar:/home/admin/test2/*

Comment: java can't recognize this command, it suggests other usage options

Comment: Can you paste the error here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247759/discussion-between-ashutosh-vaish-and-alexander-tukanov).